# Data tables load first time you look at a tab but not the second time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, datatables

I'm using `Data tables` on a number of my `Dynamic Jquery Tabs`. Each table loads fine the first time you look at a tab. But if I go back to a tab I've already viewed the data table doesn't load again.

I've noticed if Tab A has a data table, but Tab B doesn't.. if I view A then B then A the data table on A loads fine both times.

Here's the Jquery I'm using on each tab to load the table:

```
$(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bRetrieve": true,
    }); 
});
```

Here's the code I'm using  to bring the tabs in:

```
$("#MainTabs").tab();
$("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {
    var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
    var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if (typeof(contentURL) != "undefined"){ 
        $(contentID).load(contentURL, function(){ $("#MainTabs").tab(); });
    }else{
        $(contentID).tab("show");
    }   
});
$("#MainTabs a:first").tab("show");';
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique.  Are you using an ID more than once?

Comment: is it same table id or seperate table?